# PHP - Changing Value by a small market percentage

Tags: php, cron, percentage

First post, please be gentle.

I'm trying to create a simple market script where for example I have a number in my database ie 50.00 and I want to run a cron job php script to increase or decrease this randomly to a minimum of 10.00 and a maximum of 75.00.

I thought a random 0,1 follow by 2 if statements 1 `rand(-0.01,0.05)` if 2 `rand(0.01,0.05)` then `$sql = "UPDATE price SET oil='RESULT'";`

I've tried a few times at the above but I can't get it to run and the other crons in the file work.

```
    <?php
//Get Oil Price from database
$oilchange = rand(1, 2);
if ($oilchange == '1') { 
  $oilnew = rand(0.01,0.05);
//Oil price from database times oil new.

} else { 
  $oilnew = rand(-0.01,-0.05);
//Oil price from database times oil new.
}
// Update Price
?>
```

Comment: Do you get an error? What happens? Please add your actual code.

Comment: Typically you'd 'swing' the value and then check if it's in range. I.e. add the random number, then check if it's gone below 10 or above 75. That also depends how you'd like it to react when this happens (should it do nothing, or clamp it at the bounds).

Comment: you could copy-paste the code , select it and click on the `{}` button, that will format it in a readable way :)

Comment: updated code so far.

Comment: As a side point, you're checking `'1'` - that's a string (text), where as you're looking for numbers (which would just be `1`). The comparison is allowed because PHP automatically casts for you, but it costs performance and is often unreliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Rand is for integers (whole numbers)

First up, your use of rand between two decimal values (called floats) won't work, as rand is for integers only. So, you'd first want to have a random function which does output floats, like this:

```
function randomFloat($min = 0, $max = 1) {
    return $min + mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax() * ($max - $min);
}
```

Then we can safely use it between, say, 1% and 5%:

```
$percentSwing = randomFloat(0.01, 0.05);
```

Rand defaults to being 0 or 1. We can use that to randomly invert it, so we also cover -1% to -5%:

```
$percentSwing *= rand() ? 1 : -1;
```

The above could also be written like this:

```
if(rand() == 1){
    // Do nothing:
    $percentSwing *= 1;
}else{
    // Invert it:
    $percentSwing *= -1;
}
```

So, we now know how much we need to swing the number by. Let's say it was `$oilPrice`:

```
$oilPrice = 48;
```

We can just multiply the percent swing by that number to get the amount it's changing by, then add it back on:

```
$oilPrice += $percentSwing * $oilPrice;
```

So far so good! Now we need to make sure the price did not go out of our fixed range of 10 to 75. Assuming you want to 'clamp' the number - that means if it goes below 10, it's set at 10 and vice-versa, that's done like this:

```
if( $oilPrice < 10 ){
    // It went below 10 - clamp it:
    $oilPrice = 10;
}else if( $oilPrice > 75 ){
    // It went above 75 - clamp it:
    $oilPrice = 75;
}
```

The above can also be represented in one line, like this:

```
$oilPrice = max(10, min(75, $oilPrice));
```

So, that gives us the whole thing:

```
function randomFloat($min = 0, $max = 1) {
    return $min + mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax() * ($max - $min);
}

// Define the oil price (e.g. pull from your database):
$oilPrice = 48;

// get a random 1% to 5% swing: 
$percentSwing = randomFloat(0.01, 0.05);

// Invert it 50% of the time:
 $percentSwing *= rand() ? 1 : -1;

// Swing the price now:
$oilPrice += $percentSwing * $oilPrice;

// Clamp it:
$oilPrice = max(10, min(75, $oilPrice));

// Output something!
echo $oilPrice;
```

As a side note here, money in real financial systems is never stored as a float, because [rounding errors can cause major problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency).